# SharePoint page title changes

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm trying to dynamically change the title of a SharePoint page via a web part on the page, but using `Page.Title = "New Title"` in my control yields no results, assuming that somewhere down the line SharePoint overrides my changes with default page title values.

Is this possible?

Basically, I have a component on the page with links. Clicking on any of these links will reload the current page with relevant data. The link clicked on should denote the page's title. I can achieve this with JavaScript once the page has finished loading, but would like to try a coding solution first.

Comment: I think you want to be using an SPFile object that's linked to the page in the pages document library to change things in SP. `Page` is the base ASP.NET class so many things don't work as you might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to change the page title of a custom page, please try below

```
SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;

if (item != null)
{
    item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = <newTitle>;
    item.SystemUpdate(false); // this will make sure modified or modifiedby field is not updated
}
```

If you are trying to do by replacing the contentplaceholder, please check this,

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2007/08/programmatically-setting-a-web-part-pages-title/

Answer (score 1):

Add in a content editor web part into your Web Part Page, edit the HTML source and add the below javascript.

`<script type="text/javascript">
  document.title = "Your Title Goes Here";
</script>`

Comment: have a JS solution, just wanted to do it via code as stated above. thanks.